# Makefile won't compile project using sfml on Mac

Tags: macos, makefile, sfml

I am trying to compile one of my project using my custom C library based on SFML .

I have no problem compiling my project with my Makefile on Ubutun however using Mac OS X, i keep getting these errors :

```
ld: warning: ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/$USER
/.froot/lib/libsfml-audio.so, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 )
```

and

```
ld: file too small (length=8) file '/Users/$USER/.froot/lib/mylib.a' for architecture x86_64
```

My compilation flags are :

```
-L/Users/$USER/.froot/include \
-L/Users/$USER/.froot/lib \
-lmylib -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window \
-lsfml-system -lstdc++ -ldl -lm -lpthread
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile SFML on Mac as well: `*.so` are for linux only -- that's what the error refers to.

Comment: And how can I do that ?

Comment: I successfuly compiled SFML but now I get this error :
ld: file too small (length=8) file '/Users/$USER/.froot/lib/mylib.a' for architecture x86_64